# Subtable with multiple tabulars inside does not vertically align properly

Tags: tables, subfloats

The minimal example below yields weird alignment behavior for me (shown in the attached image). I tried a couple of approaches: using minipages instead of subtables didn't work, using xtabs instead of tabular solved the alignment issue, but inside each xtabular the 13th and later rows were not properly aligned, using multicols also didn't result in the desired result. I also tried adding negative space in the first column, but that doesn't change anything as well. Is this just the completely wrong way to do this? Any help appreciated.

[image: alignment error]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      \toprule
      Test & Count \\
      \midrule
      Test & 4 \\
      Test & 4 \\
      Test & 3 \\  
      Test & 3 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{tbl:one}

    \vspace{0.7cm}

    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      \toprule
      Test & Count \\
      \midrule
      Test & 38 \\    
      Test & 30 \\
      Test & 28 \\
      Test & 28 \\
      Test & 27 \\
      Test & 24 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}\hfill
  \begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
      \toprule
      Test & Count \\
      \midrule
      Test & 11 \\
      Test & 11 \\
      Test & 10 \\
      Test & 10 \\
      Test & 10 \\
      Test & 9 \\
      Test & 9 \\
      Test & 8 \\
      Test & 8 \\
      Test & 8 \\
      Test & 8 \\
      Test & 8 \\
      Test & 8 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{tbl:two}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{Main caption}
  \label{tbl:main}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing both subtables to `[c]` alignment sort of fixes it, but I think (in this case) it is because of your tabular lengths.  I agree the `[t]` option does not follow what I would expect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TeX does what it thinks it should based on your instructions. With `\begin{subtable}[t]` you're telling TeX that the reference point of the constructed box will be the same as the reference point for the top object inside. The top box inside both `subcaption` environment are produced by `tabular` environments, which place the reference point midway from the top to the bottom.

Define

```
\newcommand\rpl{\leavevmode\llap{\vrule width 6pt height 0.3pt depth 0.3pt}}
\newcommand\rpr{\leavevmode\rlap{\vrule width 6pt height 0.3pt depth 0.3pt}}
```

and place `\rpl` just before `\begin{subtable}` and `\rpr` just after `\end{subtable}`; this will draw small rules that are level with the boxes' reference points, without influencing the typesetting, because they have zero width.

[image]

This is what I get if I add `\vspace{0pt}` just after `\begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}` (still with `\rpl` and `\rpr` in place; notice that the reference points now are level with the top object, which happens to be a zero height vertical space.

[image]

(actually there is a little influence on typesetting by the small rules, because they have a tiny height, but this will vanish as soon as you remove `\rpl` and `\rpr`).

Final code, note the three `\centering` commands.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
  \toprule
  Test & Count \\
  \midrule
  Test & 4 \\
  Test & 4 \\
  Test & 3 \\  
  Test & 3 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}\label{tbl:one}

\vspace{0.7cm}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
  \toprule
  Test & Count \\
  \midrule
  Test & 38 \\
  Test & 30 \\
  Test & 28 \\
  Test & 28 \\
  Test & 27 \\
  Test & 24 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
  \toprule
  Test & Count \\
  \midrule
  Test & 11 \\
  Test & 11 \\
  Test & 10 \\
  Test & 10 \\
  Test & 10 \\
  Test & 9 \\
  Test & 9 \\
  Test & 8 \\
  Test & 8 \\
  Test & 8 \\
  Test & 8 \\
  Test & 8 \\
  Test & 8 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{tbl:two}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Main caption}\label{tbl:main}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For showing the output I added a frame to the text block

[image]